# Who were the first alien species in the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

I'm having trouble finding what the first civilization of the Star Wars galaxy.

I don't think that it's the [Celestials](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Celestial), because they are more of god-like beings.

Comment: Alien to who? After all, ET wasn't alien to him/her/its self.

Comment: Do you mean the first intelligent species? Civilized? Or does "align" specifically mean non-human (assuming the human-looking creatures in the movies are really "human")?

Comment: And first relative to what? power? age? (civilization age? first to master space fight?)

Comment: The Celestials are the architects of the galaxy.  They created the design from which everything was created... at least according to the Klikliks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

The answer is that it's either [Jerrileka](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jerrilek) who went extinct over a million years BBY, or Celestials (who were known to be active in 1MM BBY period). It's unknown when either of them started, and no mention of more ancient civilizations exist; so neither one can be considered more ancient; it's a tie.

---

I'm not quite sure what the reason is for dismissing Celestials as an answer is for you?

If it's because you believe them to be in-eligible due to being "too powerful", you have to remember that:

- The Ones were not the only Celestials. They were merely the (currently) the most powerful
- The Celestials were a race using [technology](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Celestial#Architects), not pure in-The-Force godlike beings.

From what I saw in Wookieepedia, there was no earlier sentient race mentioned anywhere.

- https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/1,000,000_BBY is listed as **the earliest known time period** (nothing listed in chronology preceding it).

> - An ancient aquatic civilization thrived on Jerrilek, but subsequently went extinct within the next million years.
> - Centerpoint Station and Sinkhole Station are completed in the Corellian system by Thuruht and other Killik hives under the direction of the Son and Daughter.
> - Centerpoint is used to create the Maw as a prison for Abeloth, with Sinkhole Station maintaining the shell of black holes from within.

---

The next chronologically would be those races who dealt with Celestials, likely starting with Killiks

> A number of species were known to have coexisted with this ancient race as far back as 100,000 BBY. These included the Gree, Kwa, Sharu, Columi, Killiks, Humans and Taung.
>   Races such as the Columi, Gree, Sharu and Kwa all had contact with the Celestials. (sources: *The Essential Atlas*, *Essential Guide to Warfare*)

Comment: As a side note, I don't think Abeloth is identified as an actual member of any civilization anywhere in canon, therefore no matter how old he/she/it is, it doesn't count

Comment: I have not found a canon identification of Abeloth's species/civilization, but the implication seems to be humanoid of some form

Comment: Also, this answer does not look at any **[extragalactic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Extra-galactic)** civilizations. as they - even had they been earlier - seem out of question's scope

Comment: Good point. The history of The Yuuzhan Vong points to a civilization thousands of years old, but no indication how many thousands or if they were even the first civilization in their galaxy

Comment: @SSumner - The YV were originally of the SW Galaxy but were banished... That is enough of that spoiler though.

Comment: @Chad - whaaaa? That's a new one to me. I only read through ~70% of the NJO, but I did read most of the Wikia for related material and it was fairly unambigously stated that Vong and some robotic species were originally from some different galaxy. Could you please elaborate? I don't mind the spoiler; or at least link.

Comment: I beleive it all comes out in [The Unifying Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Unifying_Force).  It felt like an aburpt end that was thrown in as a way to wrap the YV into a tiny bow and send them on their way.

Comment: @Chad - I've read the Unifying Force 3 or 4 times and never saw that. I think you're misinterpreting something

Comment: @SSumner - It may have been in the force heretic series.  Or even the final prophecy.  I read them with in a week of their release and have not read them since...  ZS is the homeworld of the YV it expelled them thousands of years ago dumping them in a foreign galaxy.

Comment: @Chad - Nope, Zonoma Sekot was a seed of the homeworld Yuuzhan'tar. Everything I've read has said they were extra-galactic in *origin*, down to the original plans for the NJO series. I don't think it was Force Heretic either. Maybe Final Prophecy (the only NJO novel I don't own), but I still think you're misinterpreting something.

Comment: @SSumner - I do not think so.  I reread it several times because I was like... wow that was cheap. It may have been final prophecy.  There was a round table where they discussed the NJO and yes it was ended rather abruptly and unexpectedly and not exactly on target from what was originally planned.  I think that was even included in one of the ebooks.

Comment: @Chad - what was cheap? And what ended abruptly and unexpectedly?

Comment: @sSumner - Yes and how everything tied together in a neat little bow so they could literally ship the YV off to a remote galaxy :p

Comment: @Chad - you didn't answer what was cheap. Did you not like the ending?

Comment: It seemed forced and fake... Things that extensive do not get wrapped up that neatly and tucked away that easily...  because yes it happened pretty easy.  I would have expected a generation of recovery but it is basically like it never happened.

Comment: That's not the only example of a neat little bow in the Star Wars EU. Catastrophe after catastrophe happens, and people juts move on.

Comment: @SSumner - I do not know what you mean... hmm Aldaraan is just gone and there is an asteroid field here now... Hey lets go explore that little moon!

Answer (score 3):

According to Wookieepedia, The [Columi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Columi) had achieved interstellar travel by [2,000,000 BBY](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/2,000,000_BBY). But they are also listed to do so in [100,000 BBY](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/100,000_BBY). Strangely, the source for both dates is [*Galaxy Guide 4: Alien Races*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy_Guide_4:_Alien_Races), a roleplaying game sourcebooks.

Comment: Some of the RPG materials are no longer canon (or at least N-canon), so you have to be careful with them. +1 for a great find.

Answer (score 0):

So after heavy research and a look at the galactic history timeline on Wookieepedia.

In Canon:

The Whills/The Force Priestesses are birthed by the Wellspring of Life.

Then Father, Son, Daughter, and possibly Abeloth, though she's not considered canon anymore, are born.

Then, according to "Ultimate Star Wars", The Reptillian Elders start to appear on "Ancient" Naboo.

Sources:

[Naboo Elders - Star Wars Wikia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Elders_(Naboo))

[Timeline of Galactic history - Star Wars Wikia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_galactic_history)

But that's from a source book, and I prefer in universe storytelling, so ONWWARD!

A Millennia Before the Battle of Yavin:

One or more ancestral species unlock the secrets of hyperspace travel and open the galaxy for exploration.

Sources: Tarkin

"Prime Jedi" is born.

"Force-sensitives" gather to form the Jedi Order on Ahch-To.

Sources: Nexus of Power, The Last Jedi, The Last Jedi "Expanded Edition" or unstupidly the novelization, and TLJ comic adaption.

[Timeline of Galactic history - Star Wars Wikia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_galactic_history)

6,000 BBY

The civilization on Bardotta began when the Frangawl Cult reigned over a militant society.

Sources: Nexus of Power, same timeline as before on Wookieepedia

C. 5,000 BBY

The Great Temple is built by the Massassi on Yavin 4

Sources: Journey through Space, Wookieepedia

[Journey Through Space - Star Wars Wikia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Journey_Through_Space_(2015))

So sources say the Elders from Naboo, but in-universe material states the Massassi are.

Answer (score -1):

Anzati? Since weren't they around before people started calling the Force the Force which meant they were also around before the Je'daii and Sith (race) even existed.                    On the Wookieepedia it also states that they were one of the first space faring races.

Comment: Can you provide some referencing for this answer?

Answer (score -1):

they are the celestials according to my research . some of them were the priests of force and they had spread and shared the tech and methods of force with other non-force sensitive beings and many people think they were the race who used but tech not clear in force . according to george lucas the narrator(the guy who says once upon a time long ago far far away in a galaxy) was r2d2 , he was telling it to invisible beings of force and celestials

Comment: Can you back this up with some quotes?